# passing output from function to vector C++

Tags: c++, odeint

I am new to C++ and would like to use it to solve a system of ODEs. I have used some code from the ODEINT simple example and modified it as seen below.

```
void rhs( const double YN1 , double &dYN1dz , const double z )
{
    double k1 = boost::math::cyl_bessel_k(1, z);
    double k2 = boost::math::cyl_bessel_k(2, z);
    double K = 0.0001;
    double YN1eq = (z*z*k2)/(4*g);
    double nN1eq = (3/8)*(z*z*k2);
    double D  = K*(k1/k2)*z;
    dYN1dz = -D*(YN1-nN1eq);
};

void write_cout( const double &YN1 , const double z )
{
    cout << z << ' ' << YN1 << endl;
};

typedef runge_kutta_dopri5< double > stepper_type;

int solN1()
{
    double YN1 = 0.75;
    integrate_adaptive( make_controlled( 1E-12 , 1E-12 , stepper_type()),
                        rhs , YN1 , 0.001 ,100 , 0.1 , write_cout );

};
```

I will need to use `z` and `YN1` to solve another `ODE` and so I need to store them. I am not sure how best to do so. I was thinking of using a  vector vector double to do so but I am not sure how to best proceed.

Comment: You are already storing `YN1` in a double? Can you not just do the same with `z`? Also solve another ODE where? In `sol1N`? This question is unclear ...

Comment: Question not clear IMHO... Anyway, std::tuple seems to be what you want http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple

Comment: If you want to store the sequence of `z` and `YN1` you can do this in a lambda: `vector< double > zs; vector< double >ys; integrate(...,[&zs,&ys](double y,double z) { zs.push_back(z); ys.push_back(y); } );`

Comment: Thank you, I will give that a try, looks like what I was after. Sorry about the question not being so clear. Thanks again.